java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "android.util.Size androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis$Analyzer.getDefaultTargetResolution()"
I have an app where it provides barcode scan functionality and internally i am using androidx camera library provided by google. But i am getting strange issue. If i try to run app via android studio and open scanning screen it works properly but if i build apk and install apk and open it it crashes with above abstraction error.
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "android.util.Size androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis$Analyzer.getDefaultTargetResolution()"
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis.onMergeConfig(ImageAnalysis.java:277)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.UseCase.mergeConfigs(UseCase.java:277)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.internal.CameraUseCaseAdapter.calculateSuggestedStreamSpecs(CameraUseCaseAdapter.java:682)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.internal.CameraUseCaseAdapter.updateUseCases(CameraUseCaseAdapter.java:305)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.internal.CameraUseCaseAdapter.updateUseCases(CameraUseCaseAdapter.java:267)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.internal.CameraUseCaseAdapter.addUseCases(CameraUseCaseAdapter.java:245)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.lifecycle.LifecycleCamera.bind(LifecycleCamera.java:206)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.lifecycle.LifecycleCameraRepository.bindToLifecycleCamera(LifecycleCameraRepository.java:300)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:652)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:387)
                                                                                                        at com.pharmeasy.barcode.scanners.mlkitScanner.CameraXHandlerImpl.bindAnalysisUseCase(CameraXHandlerImpl.kt:152)
                                                                                                        at com.pharmeasy.barcode.scanners.mlkitScanner.CameraXHandlerImpl.bindAllCameraUseCases(CameraXHandlerImpl.kt:79)
                                                                                                        at com.pharmeasy.barcode.scanners.mlkitScanner.CameraXHandlerImpl.setUpCamera$lambda$0(CameraXHandlerImpl.kt:69)
                                                                                                        at com.pharmeasy.barcode.scanners.mlkitScanner.CameraXHandlerImpl.$r8$lambda$X75CasY0bjqkjIyB9AlA78Ihc8I(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at com.pharmeasy.barcode.scanners.mlkitScanner.CameraXHandlerImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:6)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)


Run today in same exception (but MAUI rather then Kotlin). Problem was, that I used ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls (4.0.0) and added CommunityToolkit.Maui.Camera (1.0.5).
Perhaps it helps to check your dependencys. But here https://github.com/dotnet/android-libraries/issues/767#issuecomment-1658163275 somebody solved a situation like you described.
